# Replacing “smart quotes” in PowerShell

Tags: unicode, powershell

I'm finding myself somewhat stumped on a simple problem. I'm trying to remove fancy quoting from a bunch of text files. I've the following script, where I'm trying a number of different replacement methods, but without results.

Here's an example that downloads the data from GitHub and attempts to convert.

```
$srcUrl="https://raw.github.com/gist/1129778/d4d899088ce7da19c12d822a711ab24e457c023f/gistfile1.txt"
$wc = New-Object net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($srcUrl,"foo.txt")
$fancySingleQuotes = "[" + [string]::Join("",[char[]](0x2019, 0x2018)) + "]"

$c = Get-Content "foo.txt"
$c | % { `
        $_ = $_.Replace("’","'")
        $_ = $_.Replace("`“","`"")
        $_.Replace("`”","`"")
    } `
    |  Set-Content "foo2.txt"
```

What's the trick for this to work?

Comment: `%` [is an alias](https://pvm-professionalengineering.blogspot.com/2019/10/powershell-aliases-and-missing.html) for [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a version that works:

```
    $srcUrl="https://raw.github.com/gist/1129778/d4d899088ce7da19c12d822a711ab24e457c023f/gistfile1.txt"
    $wc = New-Object net.WebClient
    $wc.DownloadFile($srcUrl,"C:\Users\hartez\SO6968270\foo.txt")

    $fancySingleQuotes = "[\u2019\u2018]"
    $fancyDoubleQuotes = "[\u201C\u201D]"

    $c = Get-Content "foo.txt" -Encoding UTF8

    $c | % { `
        $_ = [regex]::Replace($_, $fancySingleQuotes, "'")
        [regex]::Replace($_, $fancyDoubleQuotes, '"')
    } `
    |  Set-Content "foo2.txt"
```

The reason that [manojlds' version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968270/replacing-smart-quotes-in-powershell/6968810#6968810) wasn't working for you is that the encoding on the file you're getting from GitHub wasn't compatible with the Unicode characters in the regex. Reading it in as UTF-8 fixes the problem.

Comment: the last `$_.Replace("`“","'")` does push the output line

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything imo. Why do you need to replace and assign it to $_ and then return $_? Just `[regex]::Replace($_,$fancySingleQuotes, "'")` already returns to the pipeline. And the OP is already doing it.

Comment: Starting with Powershell version 2, you can now use the -Replace operator, instead of [regex]::Replace().

$line = $line -replace '[\u2019\u2018]', "'"
$line = $line -replace '[\u201C\u201D]', '"'

Answer (score 2):

The following works on the input and output that you had given:

```
$c = Get-Content $file
$c | % { `

    $_ = $_.Replace("’","'")
    $_ = $_.Replace("`“","`"")
    $_.Replace("`”","`"")
    } `
    |  Set-Content $file
```

Comment: Indeed, it does work on the sample input text, but when run on the files I have, it does not. I've added sample files to demonstrate what I mean

Comment: It looks like it's an encoding issue - see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your last replace places a *left* fancy quote with and single quote. Is that what you want? It doesn't match your sample output. Try this:

```
$_.Replace("`“","`"")
$_.Replace("`”","`"")
```

Comment: that is my answer, but what you have given as code is wrong, `"“”"` - replace will try to replace the entire string, not individual characters. and i believe they have to be escaped as well.

Comment: @manojlds: right you are, the console was playing tricks on me. I've got to remember to use ISE for unicode.

Answer (score 0):

This Stack Overflow question is so close to what I need. I was looking for something that would check for any UTF8 and found this question:

*[How do I remove all non-ASCII characters with regex and Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889996/notepad-how-to-remove-all-non-ascii-characters-with-regex)*

Which seems to work fine in PowerShell as well.

The regex they use that works in PowerShell is:

```
[^\x00-\x7F]+
```

Which will find any UTF-8 characters. You can hone the regex if you need to be more specific.

My input only had the curly quote(s) as UTF-8 characters, so this simple substitution worked:

```
# Replace the UTF-8 quote with standard single quote
$cq = $cq -replace "[^\x00-\x7F]+", "'"
```